# Can we create a reference through another reference in java?

Tags: java, performance

I have 4 classes `test1Adapter`, `PStorageAdapter`, `Storage` & `ClientsFactory`.

**test1Adapter class**

```
public class test1Adapter extends ClientsFactory {

    public Storage TestRefToSharedStorage;
    public  test1Adapter(Storage SharedStorage) {

    this.TestRefToSharedStorage=SharedStorage;
}
    public void execute(int clientID, String text) {

        tempBuffer = new byte[TestRefToSharedStorage.pageSize];

                long firstPageNumber  = TestRefToSharedStorage.AllocatePage();
                TestRefToSharedStorage.WritePage( firstPageNumber , tempBuffer );
                TestRefToSharedStorage.ReadPage(firstPageNumber, tempBuffer );
                TestRefToSharedStorage.DeAllocatePage(firstPageNumber);
}}
```

**PStorageAdapter**

```
public class PStorageAdapter extends ClientsFactory {

    public int pageSize;

    //  create storage.
    Storage MyStorage = new Storage();

    public void execute(int clientID, String text) {

                MyStorage.LoadStorage(filename);
                MyStorage.UnloadStorage();
        }
    }
}
```

**Storage**

```
public class Storage{
private String fileName;
private long fileSize;
public RandomAccessFile file;
public int pageSize;
private int bitMapSize;

public void CreateStorage(String fileName,int pageSize, int fileSize) throws Exception{
...
}
public void LoadStorage(String fileName) throws Exception{
...
}
public void ReadPage(long n, byte [] buffer) throws Exception{
...
}
public void WritePage(long n, byte[] buffer) throws Exception{
...
}
public long AllocatePage() throws Exception{
...
}
public void DeAllocatePage(long n) throws Exception{
...
}   
public void printStats(){
...}}
```

The `test1Adapter` & `PStorageAdapter` has to extend the functionality of `ClientsFactory` class. `PStorageAdapter` class uses some function from the `storage` class. So, I created an object of type `Storage` in `PStorageAdapter` class and accessed them. Now,

**What I want to do?**

- I want to access the methods of `Storage` class within `test1Adapter` class via `PStorageAdapter` class. The reason behind it is that there should be a single object created within a session of type `Storage` which should be tweaked/used by other `PStorageAdapter` & `test1Adapter`classes otherwise it will create two separate objects which are meaningless to me.

**What I am trying to do which doesn't seem a feasible approach.**

- I tried to create a `test1Adapter` type object within `PStorageAdapter` class and passed `Storage` object in its constructor. later, I created a reference variable of type `Storage` in `test1Adapter` class which will be pointing to the above mentioned `Storage` object passed in `test1Adapter`'s constructor. It is demonstrated below

  ```
  import cyclients.PStorage.Storage;
  import cyclients.Test1.test1Adapter;
  public class PStorageAdapter extends ClientsFactory {

  //  create storage.
  Storage MyStorage = new Storage();

  public void execute(int clientID, String text) {

      MyStorage.CreateStorage(filename, pageSize, fileSize);

      if (MyStorage != null) {
          test1Adapter testing = new test1Adapter(MyStorage); 
      }
  }}
  ```

  This lead to a runtime error(**EDIT**)

  ```
  java.lang.InstantiationException: cyclients.Test1.test1Adapter
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
  ```
- Another approach is to implement inheritance at 3-levels. `test1Adapter---> PStorageAdapter --> Storage(base class)`. The `test1Adapter`, `PStorageAdapter` classes are already inheriting from the class `ClientsFactory`, then the JAVA doesn't allow this, as it needs `Multiple Inheritance`. Moreover, I need to implement the `Storage` class as an interface which I can't do because that class has already been defined in the code-base.

Moreover, the **goal is to**:

- **use** ,let say 5 of the functionalities of `Storage`class**(Total func=8 suppose)** into `PStorageAdapter` class but exposing rest **8-5=3 of them** also, later These 3 functionalities will be **used by** the `test1Adapter` class in some way.
- The above-defined goal should only use/tweak in the single copy of the `Storage` object created within a session.
- There should not be any dependency between `PStorageAdapter` class & `test1Adapter` class. For Example, I tied the object creation of `test1Adapter` class withing `execute() method of storage adapter class`, this means until I execute the above method, the `test1Adapter` will never be invoked.!. This not what I want.
- Also, The `test1Adapter` & `PStorageAdapter` has to extend the functionality of `ClientsFactory` class.

Keeping above contraints into picture, could anyone in the community provide an approach to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that's a "compile time" error? A exception stacktrace usually indicates either a runtime error or a compiler bug.

Comment: @killjoy, thanks for highlighting it. I believe it's a runtime error. I will edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a combination of using dependency injection along with the adapter pattern.  The dependency injection insures the different objects are working on the same `Storage` instance, and the adapter limits the exposure of `Storage` methods.  The part you didn't describe in your post would be something like a `SessionManager` class to coordinate the work.

For example, `Storage` defines 8 public methods:

```
public class Storage {
    public void method1(){}
    public void method2(){}
    public void method3(){}
    public void method4(){}
    public void method5(){}
    public void method6(){}
    public void method7(){}
    public void method8(){}
}
```

But `PStorage` wraps a `Storage` to only expose methods 1 through 5:

```
public class PStorage {
    private final Storage storage;

    public PStorage(Storage storage) {
       this.storage = storage;
    }

    public void method1(){storage.method1();}
    public void method2(){storage.method2();}
    public void method3(){storage.method3();}
    public void method4(){storage.method4();}
    public void method5(){storage.method5();}
}
```

And `TestStorage` wraps a `Storage` to only expose methods 6 through 8:

```
public class TestStorage {
    private final Storage storage;

    public PStorage(Storage storage) {
       this.storage = storage;
    }

    public void method6(){storage.method6();}
    public void method7(){storage.method7();}
    public void method8(){storage.method8();}
}
```

So then a `PStorageAdapter` (is this a good name?) works on a `PStorage` instance:

```
public class PStorageAdapter extends ClientsFactory {
    private final PStorage storage;

    public PStorageAdapter(PStorage storage) {
        this.storage = storage;
   }

    public execute(...) {
        // can only call storage.method1() through storage.method5()
    }
}
```

And a `TestStorageAdapter` (is this a good name?) works on a `TestStorage` instance:

```
public class TestStorageAdapter extends ClientsFactory {
    private final TestStorage storage;

    public TestStorageAdapter(TestStorage storage) {
        this.storage = storage;
   }

    public execute(...) {
        // can only call storage.method6() through storage.method8()
    }
}
```

And finally, some class to coordinate/manage the activity (possibly a Singleton?)

```
public class SessionManager {
    Map<String, Storage> sessions = new ...;

   public getPStorageAdapterFor(String sessionId)  {
       return new PStorageAdapter(new PStorage(getStorage(sessionId)));
   }

   public getTestStorageAdapterFor(String sessionId)  {
       return new TestStorageAdapter(new TestStorage(getStorage(sessionId)));
   }

   private Storage getStorageFor(String sessionId)  {
       Storage storage = sessions.get(sessionId);
       if (storage == null) {
          storage = new Storage();
          sessions.put(sessionId, storage);
       }

       return storage;
   }
```

}

Comment: Thanks for refining the design. When I say a session, I mean, there is a GUI that is calling the execute method of each class, TestStorage & PStorage (these calls are actually API calls which we named as commands within GUI.) and display the computed result in the GUI's output pane. When I run the whole code-base, the GUI gets opened, that's a session, within that session, I used pStorage's functions, let say CreateStorage() & loadStorage(), literally as the name suggests it does that, later, I used testStorage to manipulate within this created storage at bit/byte level.

Comment: How I will capture the sessionID of the GUI in the SessionManager class you mentioned above to actually keep the Storage object single.? So, that at any point in time(active session/ runtime env/ in GUI ), either Pstorage or testStorage can manipulate it only without creating another new object.? please suggest.

Comment: Somewhere in the start up of the GUI you could create a `Storage` instance, along with `PStorageAdapter` and `TestStorageAdapter` instances to wrap the `Storage` instance.  Provide getter methods so all interactions then go through the adapters.